# Marking the Initial State of this Finite Automaton

Tags: java, debugging, dictionary

I'm working on a finite deterministic automaton based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870519/modelling-a-finite-deterministic-automaton-via-this-data).

From this code:

```
 public void markInitialState (int initialStateId) {

                    State theInitialState = allStates.get(initialStateId);
                    theInitialState.isInitial=true;
                    allStates.add(initialStateId, theInitialState);

                /*DEBUG*/

                System.out.println(" THE INITIAL STATE ID IS " + initialStateId);

                theInitialState = allStates.get(initialStateId);
                if ((theInitialState.isInitial)==true)
                System.out.println("THE STATE " + theInitialState + " IS MARKED AS INITIAL");

        }
```

I'm getting the line:

```
THE STATE {d=(this Map), e=(this Map), a=(this Map)} IS MARKED AS INITIAL
```

On the line that should say:

```
THE STATE 2 IS MARKED AS INITIAL
```

Why is the Map doing this?

I don't get why it's marking the final states correctly using the same aproach.

The Input file is:

```
4
3 2 1
ab
1 0
2 0
2 0
2
0 3
abaa
aab
aba
3 3 2
ade
0 1 2
1 2 0
2 1 0
1 2
2 2
a
de
3 2 1
ab
1 0
2 0
2 0
2
0 3
abaa
aab
aba
3 3 2
ade
0 1 2
1 2 0
2 1 0
1 2
2 2
a
de
```

The code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package afd;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("E://Documents and Settings//Administrator//My Documents//NetBeansProjects//AFD//src//afd//dfa.in");


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String firstLine= br.readLine();


        String [] firstLineSplitted = firstLine.split(" ");

        /*debug*/
        System.out.println("firstLine is " + firstLine);

        int numberOfTestCases = Integer.parseInt(firstLine);

        for (int indexOfTestCases =0; indexOfTestCases < numberOfTestCases; indexOfTestCases++  ){



            String caseStartLine = br.readLine();

            /*debug*/
            System.out.println("caseStarLine is " + caseStartLine);
            String [] caseStartLineSplitted = caseStartLine.split(" ");

            int numberOfStates;
            int numberOfAlphabetSymbols;
            int numberOfFinalStates;


            numberOfStates = Integer.parseInt(caseStartLineSplitted[0]);

            numberOfAlphabetSymbols = Integer.parseInt(caseStartLineSplitted[1]);

            numberOfFinalStates = Integer.parseInt(caseStartLineSplitted[2]);




            Automaton automaton = new Automaton();


            automaton.setAllStates(numberOfStates);

  //          automaton.size = numberOfStates;
 //           automaton.numberOfAlphabetSymbols = numberOfAlphabetSymbols;
 //           automaton.numberOfFinalStates = numberOfFinalStates;
            //Automaton a = new Automaton(numberOfStates);


            String alphabetLine = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("alphabetLine is " + alphabetLine);

            automaton.setAlphabet (alphabetLine);

//            automaton.alphabetSymbols =new StringBuffer(alphabetLine);

            for (int indexOfStates = 0; indexOfStates < numberOfStates; indexOfStates++){

                  String transitionsLine = br.readLine();
                   /*debug*/
                   System.out.println("transitionsLine is " + transitionsLine);

                   automaton.setTransitions(indexOfStates,transitionsLine);

                  /*String [] ijLineSplitted = ijLine.split(" ");

                  int i = Integer.parseInt(ijLineSplitted[0]);
                  int j = Integer.parseInt(ijLineSplitted[1]);
                    */

            }

            String finalStatesLine = br.readLine();
            /*debug*/
            System.out.println("finalStatesLine is " + finalStatesLine);
            String finalStatesLineSplitted [] = finalStatesLine.split(" ");

            automaton.markFinalStates(finalStatesLineSplitted);



            String initialStateAndNumberOfStringsLine = br.readLine();

            /*debug*/
            System.out.println("initialStateAndNumberOfStringsLine  is " +initialStateAndNumberOfStringsLine);
            String [] splittedInitialStateLine = initialStateAndNumberOfStringsLine.split(" ");

            int initialState = Integer.parseInt(splittedInitialStateLine[0]);
            int numberOfStrings = Integer.parseInt(splittedInitialStateLine[1]);

            automaton.markInitialState(initialState);

            for (int stringIndex =0; stringIndex<numberOfStrings; stringIndex++){

                 String stringToProcess = br.readLine();
                 /*debug*/
            System.out.println("stringToProcess is " + stringToProcess);


            }


         }
        }







}


class State extends HashMap<Character, State>{

boolean isFinal;
boolean isInitial;

State () {
    isInitial=false;
    isFinal = false;
    }

}

  class Automaton{
     List <State> allStates;
    //private List<State> finalStates;
     State initialState;
     State currentState;
      char [] alphabet;




    Automaton() {


        allStates = new ArrayList<State>();


    }

    public void setAllStates (int numberOfStates)  {

        for (int i =0; i <numberOfStates; i++) {

            State newState = new State();
            allStates.add(newState);

         }

    }


    public void setAlphabet (String alphabetLine){

        alphabet = alphabetLine.toCharArray();




    }

    public void markFinalStates (String [] finalStates){

        for (int index =0; index<finalStates.length; index++) {

            int aFinalStateId = Integer.parseInt(finalStates[index]);

            State aFinalState = allStates.get(aFinalStateId);
            aFinalState.isFinal = true;
            allStates.add(aFinalStateId, aFinalState);


            /*DEBUG*/
            aFinalState = allStates.get(aFinalStateId);
            if ((aFinalState.isFinal)==true)
            System.out.println("THE STATE " + aFinalStateId + " IS MARKED AS FINAL");

        }

    }

    public void markInitialState (int initialStateId) {

            State theInitialState = allStates.get(initialStateId);
            theInitialState.isInitial=true;
            allStates.add(initialStateId, theInitialState);

            /*DEBUG*/

            System.out.println(" THE INITIAL STATE ID IS " + initialStateId);

            theInitialState = allStates.get(initialStateId);
            if ((theInitialState.isInitial)==true)
            System.out.println("THE STATE " + theInitialState + " IS MARKED AS INITIAL");

    }


    public void setTransitions(int stateId, String transitionsLine){


            State theOneToChange = allStates.get(stateId);

            String [] statesToReachStringSplitted = transitionsLine.split(" ");

            for (int symbolIndex=0; symbolIndex<statesToReachStringSplitted.length;symbolIndex++){

                int reachedState= Integer.parseInt(statesToReachStringSplitted[symbolIndex]);

                theOneToChange.put(alphabet[symbolIndex],allStates.get(reachedState));

                System.out.println("THE STATE " + stateId + " REACHES THE STATE " + reachedState + " WITH THE SYMBOL " + alphabet[symbolIndex]);

            }

            allStates.add(stateId, theOneToChange);

    }


    public boolean processString (String string)
    {


        boolean accepted = false;

        return accepted;


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void markInitialState (int initialStateId) {

        State theInitialState = allStates.get(initialStateId);
        theInitialState.isInitial=true;
        allStates.add(initialStateId, theInitialState);

        /*DEBUG*/

        System.out.println(" THE INITIAL STATE ID IS " + initialStateId);

        theInitialState = allStates.get(initialStateId);
        if ((theInitialState.isInitial)==true)
        System.out.println("THE STATE " + theInitialState + " IS MARKED AS INITIAL");

}
```

On the last line of this method, you're printing `theInitialState` instead of `initialStateID`.