# Modeling DFA and NFA using HashMap Implementation

Tags: java, dfa, nfa

I have to implement the following operations over automata in Java:

- Concatenation
- Kleene Star
- Union
- Intersection

Those operations are easier if the automaton is an NFA. I liked the implementation given in the following link [Modelling a Finite Deterministic Automaton via this data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1870519/657649) but I think this does not fit well when modeling NFA, because of the key uniqueness restriction. Would you recommend me any workaround to modeling NFAs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone who actually implemented these operations once (when building a scanner generator), I recommend building up the automaton as an NFA, then using an algorithm like the subset construction or Thompson's algorithm to convert it down to a DFA.  This keeps the logic for combining automata together simple and elegant without sacrificing the speed of the resulting matching automaton.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. How would you consider modeling the NFA? which data structure is best suited to my purpose? is there any possibility of using a HashMap or should I look out for other options?

Comment: I recommend having a class representing each state.  Each state then stores a set of all states reachable by epsilon transitions, plus a map from symbols to the set of states for which there is a transition entering that state on a symbol.

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-state for an awesome discussion using Java and implementing the state design pattern templatetypedef just suggested.

Comment: Thompson's algorithm is using for convert Regex to NFA

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using DFA's.  Though forming the NFA maybe easier on paper, checking a valid string against an NFA will be more complicated than verifying one against a DFA due to accounting for epsilon-jumps.

As far as modeling them, you should be able to write your own with only a few classes.  Just think of what a DFA/NFA consists of:
- Start state
- Set of states (some of which are "acceptance" states)
- Set of transitions

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason why I'm doing this with NFAs is because I need to get an expression from the user that is an extended regex (that is, with intersection and complement) and give as an output the regex with the three basic operations (union, intersection and Kleene Star).